# Working with Paypal cancel_return

Tags: php, paypal, laravel-5, return, paypal-sandbox

I'm doing my project with laravel 5 and here I have to do payment with paypal. I got this code and doing well with my payments. But when someone goto paypal and if he return without doing payment `cancel_return` works.It's fine. But I don't know how to handle the `$_GET` when return Here is my route also

`Route::get('/paypal/cancel','Paypal\PaypalController@paypalCancel');`

I'm using this code to move to paypal page with my sandbox account.

```
form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="paypal">

        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to example" />
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx@gmail.com" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="{{$data['p_name']}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{$data['tot']}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services" />
        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="{{url('/paypal/return')}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="{{url('/paypal/notify')}}"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="{{url('/paypal/cancel')}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" id="custom" name="custom" value="{{$data['id']}}"/>
        <input type="hidden" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"/>

    </form>
```

Just tell me what should I have do when user cancel his payment in paypal login and return..Thanks..

Comment: Is there anybody to help me. This ruins my day guys..

Comment: I think you should refer to paypal documentation on how to cancel a payment. Paypal provides an API that developers can use all you have to do is to understand how it works.

Comment: sorry can't provide a code for you its been a while since I've use Paypal

Comment: I just want to know what kind of thing do I get from  paypal when cancel a payment ..Say in return it send seller details, buyer details, amount paid and we can grab it from $_POST[] .. In this case what is happening.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user cancels payment in PayPal, the next action is up to you. You can either display a "Payment was canceled" page to inform the user that they canceled the payment, or you can prompt them to try payment again.

The `cancel_return` URL is purely there so developers can show a friendly message when payment has been canceled.

Comment: Can I get the value added to custom hidden field when return without doing payments

Comment: You can capture the ```$_GET``` data and store directly if you wish. But there won't be much useful information in there, except a flag that says payment was canceled.

Comment: I asked this question related to this. Can you answer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370621/append-value-to-existing-session-laravel-5