# Append value to existing session Laravel 5

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

Once in my login I set values of user to session like this..

```
session()->set("user", $user);
```

And for get the values of the session from anywhere in my application attach with it to `$request` `$request->_user = $user;` like this. So I can get it like this from anywhere

`$user = $request->_user;`

Thing is I want pass some ID of purchase order at the midle of the application. So can I attach it to existing session or how to create new session and append the ID. With that ID, page redirect to paypal and If user cancel the payment I can catch his canceled payment with that ID. That is why I thought session would help me. After a successful payment it is OK to destroy that session. Help me !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can continue to append data to the session while the user is using your application. Assuming you want to store a array of purchase IDs, you can do:

```
session()->push('item_ids', 'item1');

session()->push('item_ids', 'item3');
```

This will create an array so you can later save all the IDs that the user attempted to purchase:

```
$items = session('item_ids');
```

This will return an array with all the `item_ids` you've pushed to the array:

```
[
  'item1',
  'item3'
]
```

After successful purchase or after you've saved the canceled purchase details, just start a new session or delete the item_ids.

```
// generate new session
session()->regenerate();

// delete item_ids
session()->forget('item_ids');
```

Comment: Is this not getting conflict with my existing `_user` session

Comment: No, because the data is saved under two different keys: ```user``` and ```item_ids```.

Comment: Yep, and then if you do ```$request->session()->set("item_ids", "7");```, the ```item_ids``` will return ```[ 5, 7 ]```.